# Playframework get Users

Tags: html, groovy, playframework

im trying to pass a list of users but just apear in command line i just get Users: [null, null , null]

can some one help me?
thanks

my view:

```
#{field 'project.projectUser'}
    <label for="${field.id}">Select Users: </label>                 
    #{list userList , as:'user'}
        <input id="${field.id}" type="checkbox" name="${field.name}" value="${user}"/> ${user.Name}
   #{/list}
#{/field}
```

my controler

```
public static void handleSubmit(Project project) {

    System.out.println("\n Users: "+project.projectUsers);

    for (ProjectUsers x : project.projectUsers) {
        System.out.println(x.Name);
    }

    render();
}
```

Project.java

```
   @Entity 
   public class Project extends Model{

    public String name;

     @ManyToMany( cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
     public List<User> projectUsers;

    public Project(String name){
        this.name=name;
        this.projectUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
    }

public Project addUsers(List<User> users) {

    projectUsers.addAll(users);
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the final evaluation of "${field.name}" ?

Regarding your controller, it should work with something like "project.projectUsers[]".
BTW, I think it only work if project.projectUsers is a list of simple types (long, string).

Regards

Comment: its a list, @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) public List<ProjectUsers> projectUsers;

Answer (score 0):

You should post more code, but as a wild guess, try ${user.name} instead of ${user.Name}

Edit: Actually, I think this might be just a typo: project.projectUsers vs project.projectUser

Comment: witch code do you whant? the user.Name, works fine the problem is the value, in the basictest, it works in here it doen't

Comment: @Daniel we would need the model at least, and possibly the HTML resulting from the current snippet...

Comment: To reiterate my edit above, I think this is a typo: #{field 'project.projectUser'} should be #{field 'project.projectUsers'}